# double integral with trapezoid rule in language C

Tags: c, math

I was trying to implement a program in which I can calculate a double integral as a function of x and y with the trapezium rule (that's the one I understood the best). However, in addition to not getting the result I want the program has a very large calculation time for very large n ranges.

I thought first of calculating the integral of the function with respect to y, and then in the body of the program it calls it in relation to the parameters presented and calculate its value in function of x, but it did not work very well and I can not think of a way to do it.

Could someone help me to implement the program correctly and more efficiently?

here is the code as far as i did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double f(double x, double y, double ay,double  by, double ny);
int main()
{

    int i;
    int nx = 0;


    double ax, bx;
    double sumx = 0;
    double soma=0;
    double hx,hy;
    double x,y;
    double ay,by;
    int ny;

    printf("inferior limit ax = ");
    scanf("%lf", &ax);
    printf("upper limit  bx (b>a) = ");
    scanf("%lf", &bx);
    printf("interval nx (n>1) n = ");
    scanf("%d", &nx);

    hx = (bx - ax) / (nx - 1);
    x = ax;

    printf("inferior limit ay = ");
    scanf("%lf", &ay);
    printf("upper limit by (b>a) = ");
    scanf("%lf", &by);
    printf("interval ny (n>1) n = ");
    scanf("%d", &ny);

    for (i = 1; i <= nx - 1; i++)
    {
        sumx = sumx + f(x,y,ay,by,ny) + f(x + hx,y,ay,by,ny);
        x = x + hx;
    }


    sumx = sumx * (hx / 2);

    printf("O resultado da soma e': %lf\n", sumx);

    return 0;
} // end main()


//
//
//
double f(double x, double y, double ay,double  by, double ny)
{
    double func;
    int j=0;
    double hy;
    double sumy=0;

    func= sin(x+y) / ((x*x) + y);

    hy = (by - ay) / (ny -1);
    y= ay;

    for (j =1; j <= ny - 1; j++)
    {
        sumy = sumy + sin(x + (y + hy)/ (x*x) + y+ hy);
        y = y +hy;
    }

    return sumy = sumy * (hy / 2);
} // end f()
```

Comment: You don't assign anything to `y` in `main()`, yet you pass its value to `f()`. There, you use it to compute `func`, but you never use `func`. `j<=ny-1` is the same as `j<ny`. You can also use `sumy+=sin()` instead of `sumy=sumy+sin()`. None of these things will make your code a whole lot faster, but cleaning up things like these will make it easier to read and comment on.

Comment: Instead of `for (i = 1; i <= nx - 1; i++)` you can loop as `for(x=ax;x<bx;x+=hx)`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo `for(x=ax;x<bx;x+=hx)` would be a bad idea due to accumulated round-off errors of `x+=hx`  `for(integer count)` is much better.

Comment: "to not getting the result I want" --> post the input use, output seen, output expected.

Comment: @chux Sure, `for(int...)` is better, but if inside the loop you do `x=x+hx` and the `int` value is not being used, then there's no difference. Except with the `int` count you might end exceeding your upper boundary. Actually, it would be best if the last iteration were computed using `bx` instead of `x+hx` as the right end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works in principle, but there are two errors when you accumulate over y.

The most important error is that you have garbled the parentheses when calculating your function. Your function is:

```
func = sin(x + y) / (x*x + y);
```

When you accumulate the areas in ´f`, you calculate`func(x, y + hy)` like so:

```
sumy = sumy + sin(x + (y + hy)/ (x*x) + y + hy);
```

If we assume that the first function is correct, this should be written as:

```
sumy = sumy + sin(x + (y + hy)) / (x*x + y + hy);
```

If you increment `y` first, you can use the same expression for `func(x, y)`. A better way would probably be to put the evaluation of (f(x, y) into a separate function.

The second error is that when you accumulate the trapezoids in `f`, you must add both end points, but you only add one. Fix this with:

```
sumy = sumy + sin(x + y) / (x*x + y);
y = y + hy;
sumy = sumy + sin(x + y) / (x*x + y);
```

These changes should give you the correct answer. There are other minor errors, for example you don't initialise `y`, but pass it to `f`. In your case, this doesn't matter, because you shouldn't pass `y` to `f` in the first place; it should be a local variable, because it isn't used outside of `f`.

#### Optimisation

The code to calculate the trapezoidal rule is the code above is O(n²), where n is the number of intervals in both x and y direction. That means that execution time will increase drastically if you use many intervals.

A simple optimisation is to improve the constant factor. The algorithm must evaluate all points in the n×m grid, but the code above will evaluate all inner points four times all points on the edges twice. You can evaluate all points only once instead and multiply points in the middle, at the edges and at the corners with a factor of 1.0, 0.5 and 1.25 respectively.

[*Note*: In an earlier version, I wrote that the evaluation of the two directions cannot be separated. The discussion above makes it clear that this isn't true.]

Comment: Very good answer aside from `if (fabs(den) < 1.0e-12) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Division by zero!\n");`   The rational for using a non-zero value deserves commentary.  The `1.0e-12` is arbitrary.  IOWs, a magic number.

Comment: Are you sure that numerical integration is not separable? I don't see a proof for separability immediately, but I also can't find a counterexample easily. I'm on the fence about this one for now. Other than that, a good answer. With the algorithm written like this. I came to realize that all that the trapezoidal rule does is add the function value at regular points. You are adding the value at each point 4 times, and dividing by 4. You could also just add `f(x0,y0)` in the inner loop, then not divide by 4 at the end. You would have to adjust the loop limits so that `j<=ny`. and `i<=nx`.

Comment: ...and if you do that, then you immediately see that it's separable too. And also easy to parallelize.

Comment: I could not understand these two parts 
     double x0 = ax + i * hx;
     double x1 = ax + (i + 1) * hx;

And

double y0 = ay + j * hy;
double y1 = ay + (j + 1) * hy;

how are you calculating the volume of the prism within each interval?

and thanks for all the answers

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I had written the nswer the straightforward way and left the optimization "as exercise for the reader". Unlike you, I didn't make the next mental step, though. My statement that the order of evaluation matters is clearly wrong. I don't think that adding all values is the trapezoidal rule, which would require to evaluate edges with a factor of 0.5 and corners with a factor of 0.25. You could turn the rule into a "rectangular"/"cuboid" rule where you evaluate the mid-points of the cells.

Comment: @chux: Thanks. You are right, the limit was pulled from thin air. I'm not quite sure how to handle the poles here. I guess that any integration interval that is crossed by x² + y = 0 cannot safely be calculated, so that should be checked for beforehand. The evaluation points might even all yield normal values, but they are meaningless if the values in between could be +/- infinity.

Comment: @JulioSilva: In the light of the insighful comments, I will have to update the answer. But not right now -- I must cook and eat dinner first.

Comment: @MOehm Could use `if (fabs(den) <= 1.0/DBL_MAX...` to pre-test if `sin(x + y) / den` will overflow/div0.

Comment: @MOehm You're right, the edge and corner samples need to weighted differently. Using the mid points of the cells is a good solution, but even if  the approximation is equally good, plenty of people will complain it's not the trapezoidal rule...

Comment: @JulioSilva: When I revisited my answer, I found the actual error in your code: mispositioned parantheses in the formula when you calculate f(x, y + hy). I've edited the answer.